# Do I need Windows 10 clean install partitions?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I got a brand new 1TB SSD to do a clean install of Windows 10. When it came time to choose the partition, I chose the "Primary" partition and clicked next. Windows then successfully installed.

However, when I checked the drive partitions, I didn't see any of the typical partitions that come with installing Windows, such as "Recovery", "MSR(Reserved)", or "System".

My installation of Windows 10 works fine, so I'm not sure what to make of this. Do I need any of these partitions? Do the files that go on these partitions even exist? Perhaps during the installation, did Windows just put everything on the "Primary" partition?

Information: I used Rufus to create a bootable disk using ISO image. The partition scheme and target system type is MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI. THe file system was NTFS.

Comment: Did you have an existing system disk also installed when you installed Windows

Comment: No. I only had the fresh 1TB SSD with the bootable USB drive.

Comment: If the system boots with only the SSD installed then everything is fine

Comment: What did you mean "target system type is MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEF"? A system setup firmware is either a BIOS version or UEFI and will not be both. If it is UEFI then and MBR install would have used MBR\Legacy or CSM mode.